# Python: How to use different logfiles for processes in multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool` to run a number of independent processes in parallel. Not so much different from the basic example in the python docs:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I would like each process to have a separate log file. I log various info from other modules in my codebase and some third-party packages (none of them is multiprocessing aware). So, for example, I would like this:

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    logging.info(f"x*x={x*x}")
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, range(10)))
```

to write on disk:

```
log1.log
log2.log
log3.log
log4.log
log5.log
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Alright I think a separate question makes more sense. Please re-ask your initial question but change the title to "How to use different logfiles for items in multiprocessing.Pool?" and exchange the sentence "I would like each process..." with "On the worker-side I would like to use separate logfiles for each item of the iterable passed to `pool.map()`."

Comment: here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436068/python-how-to-use-a-different-log-file-for-each-task-in-multiprocessing-pool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use Pool's `initializer()` to set up and register the separate loggers immediately after workers start up. Under the hood the arguments to `Pool(initializer)` and `Pool(initargs)` end up being passed to `Process(target)` and `Process(args)` for creating new worker-processes...

Pool-workers get named in the format {start_method}PoolWorker-{number}, so e.g. `SpawnWorker-1` if you use spawn as starting method for new processes.
The file number for the logfiles then can be extracted from the assigned worker-names with `mp.current_process().name.split('-')[1]`.

```
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp


def f(x):
    logger.info(f"x*x={x*x}")
    return x*x


def _init_logging(level=logging.INFO, mode='a'):
    worker_no = mp.current_process().name.split('-')[1]
    filename = f"log{worker_no}.log"
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename, mode=mode)
    fmt = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s --- %(message)s'
    )
    fh.setFormatter(fmt)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    globals()['logger'] = logger


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with mp.Pool(5, initializer=_init_logging, initargs=(logging.DEBUG,)) as pool:
        print(pool.map(f, range(10)))
```

Note, due to the nature of multiprocessing, there's no guarantee for the exact number of files you end up with in your small example.
Since `multiprocessing.Pool` (contrary to `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`) starts workers as soon as you create the instance, you're bound to get the specified `Pool(process)`-number of files, so in your case 5. Actual thread/process-scheduling by your OS might cut this number short here, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
is there a way to name the log file in a more meaningful way? I use each process to build a binary artifact from human readable data. Each binary file has a name, I'd like to use the same name for the log file. Would that be possible?

Comment: @RobertoArista You can name the file however you like, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I need to pass the filename into the `_init_logger` function, right? How can I access from there the process to access the binary artifact name?

Comment: @RobertoArista I start to wonder if you accidentally asked the wrong question in the first place. Does it even matter to you which _process_ does what and are you aware that process != task? Should every item in `.map(iterable)` end up being logged to a separate file?

Comment: Yep, exactly. I don't have any experience with `multiprocessing`, was not aware of the different terminology. What's the policy in this case? Should I edit the question or ask another one?

Comment: @RobertoArista So your `[1, 2, 3]` was actually the name-parts for the logfiles then. I think your question is quite good because it's very little code and something that other people might look for. I'm not sure yet if we should extend the question to another case or make another one. I'd say don't ask another question for now, I will work something out and let you know.

Comment: Alright, looking forward!