# Python: How to use a different logfile for each item in multiprocessing.Pool?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool` to run a number of independent tasks in parallel. Not so much different from the basic example in the python docs:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

I would like each item to log to a separate file. I log various info from other modules in my codebase and some third-party packages (none of them is multiprocessing aware). So, for example, I would like this:

```py
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def logOnDisk(x):
    logging.info("hello world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(logOnDisk, ["ping", "pong", "foo", "bar"])
```

to write on disk:

```
ping.log
pong.log
foo.log
bar.log
```

Each file should contain the string "hello world".
How do I achieve this?

Comment: You really want a logfile _per item_ of the iterable, not per task as became clear in our previous discussion. A task could be made of a chunk comprising multiple of the items in the iterable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a separate logfile for every processed item (of the iterable you pass to `pool.map()`) from inside the workers, nothing multiprocessing-specific is really needed. But you can
can use Pool's `initializer()` to set up the root-loggers inside the workers and store some meta-data for logging. Under the hood the arguments to `Pool(initializer)` and `Pool(initargs)` end up being passed to `Process(target)` and `Process(args)` for creating new worker-processes.
Then you only have to exchange the `Filehandler` for every item processed with `log_on_disk()` inside the workers.

```
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp


def log_on_disk(x):
    logger = _init_logger(file_id=x)
    logger.info(f"hello world")


def _init_logging(level=logging.INFO, mode='a'):
    fmt = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(processName)-10s %(name)s %(levelname)-8s --- %(message)s'
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(level)
    globals()['_log_meta'] = {'mode': mode, 'fmt': fmt}


def _init_logger(file_id):
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.handlers = []  # remove all handlers
    fh = logging.FileHandler(f"{file_id}.log", mode=_log_meta['mode'])
    fh.setFormatter(_log_meta['fmt'])
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    return logger


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with mp.Pool(5, initializer=_init_logging, initargs=(logging.DEBUG,)) as pool:
       pool.map(log_on_disk, ["ping", "pong", "foo", "bar"])
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Darkonaut got the proper solution. I misunderstood the question as I believed "logging" to be a generic placeholder module, and not an actual module.**

If you just want the dead-simple method, then you could do:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def logOnDisk(x):
    f = open(''.join(x + ".log"), "w+")
    f.write("hello world")
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(logOnDisk, ["ping", "pong", "foo", "bar"])
```

You can of course move the contents of LogOnDisk into logging or logging.info:

main.py:

```
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool

def logOnDisk(x):
    logging.info(x, "hello world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(logOnDisk, ["ping", "pong", "foo", "bar"])
```

logging.py:

```
class info:
    def __init__(self, filename, log_message):
        f = open(''.join(filename + ".log"), "w+")
        f.write(log_message)
        f.close()
```

Further refinement would give us:

main.py:

```
from logging import logger
from multiprocessing import Pool

def logOnDisk(x):
    logger_obj = logger(x)
    logger_obj.info("hello world")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(logOnDisk, ["ping", "pong", "foo", "bar"])
```

logging.py:

```
class logger:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.f = open(''.join(filename + ".log"), "w+")

    def __del__(self):
        self.f.close()

    def info(self, logString):
        self.f.write(logString)
```

Comment: this solution does not take into account third-party packages

Comment: @RobertoArista The above code is an example on how to fix the problem stated in the question. I can update it to move the contents of LogOnDisk into a logging module for clarification.

Comment: @RobertoArista It has been done. If you would like me to further expand the explanation, then please give me a heads up.

Comment: While this might work, I would not recommend it, because you are shadowing the official logging module, which is confusing and will make the code hard to understand

Comment: @TanjaBayer I was not aware that this was an official module. I've always used "logging" or "logger" as a generic placeholder such as "mystring" or "myfunc". I'll edit the response and keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @Decclo in the question I state that "I log various info from other modules in my codebase and some third-party packages"

Comment: @RobertoArista Yes, but you can still log content from other modules even if you write your own logger (obviously). As said before, I didn't know that the module you use for logging (and not whose content you log) also was a third party module. The answer should have been updated accordingly.